# How to reliably install an app on Mac?

Tags: mac, installation, dmg-image

When I download a DMG installer app and then double-click it, I am supposed to drag the app icon onto the Application folder icon:

[image]

When I do that, there is NO REACTION or VISUAL FEEDBACK (except a strange sound after a few seconds), so I am not sure whether the installation was successful.

Logically, I would expect a confirmation dialog like e.g. "The app has been successfully installed".

I am not sure whether there is a more RELIABLE method to install an app on Mac.

macOS Monterey 12.01

Comment: “except a strange sound after a few seconds” That “strange sound” is just the macOS copying is done sound. In this case, the application was copied off of the disk image and copied into your system’s applications directory. This is not unusual. Dozens of installers work like this. There is no formal “installation” past copying the file into the applications directory. “I am not sure whether there is a more RELIABLE method to install an app on Mac.” The bigger question is why you consider copying a file to be unreliable.

Comment: "why you consider copying a file to be unreliable" - When I copy a file in Finder then I have a VISUAL FEEDBACK of the copy process. When I do that from the installer window then there is no visual feedback. Hence the importance of a confirmation dialog.

Comment: It's just too fast to register. File copies going wrong is probably less than one in a million. If it failed, you can be sure it would tell you.

Comment: ***Ah… btw, get off 12.01 as soon as humanly possible. It is as buggy as all hell.*** [which has no relation to your assumed issue, just as general advice].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misconception of what constitutes an install process.

Comment: @Tetsujin Define "install process".

Comment: We've defined it until we're blue in the face. See existing comments & answers. You seem to still be insisting on some kind of Windows bit by bit copy using a 20-year-old method of tediously putting bits of files & dlls etc into various separate locations, tagging the registry with relevant data… It's just not necessary, so it's not done for most installs. If it is required, the app will have an actual installer [& an actual uninstaller too].

Comment: @Tetsujin, Your assumptions are WRONG. If you cannot define "install process," your statement "question is based on a misconception of what constitutes an install process" is WRONG because UNDEFINED. Use LOGIC.

Comment: OK. Install. *The process by which an application and its dependencies are copied to the correct places in order that the operating system may run it.* A Mac app is a self-contained unit [a folder disguised as a single file]. Therefore, the installation process is covered by copying that folder/file to the Applications directory. As a copy process is only important to report to the user if it fails, then the 'copy finished' sound is sufficient acknowledgement that it was successful. I'm now done with this pointless discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem here may be your *expectation.*

All that is happening is that you are dragging the app from the opened DMG file to the /Applications folder. EG you are just **copying** a file (or more correctly an application package, which is essentially a folder) from one location to another.

This happens to me with regularity, sometimes I don't even see the copying progress dialog because it is obscured by another window or it comes and goes so quickly I don't notice it. This is normal when you have really fast storage (in other words an SSD) and small(ish) files.

Try copying a document of some sort from your Mac to a USB drive. Then copy it back. Copying back will be faster but, depending on the size of the file, perhaps not enough to see the difference.

Also when you copy the file, do you get the same "strange sound" as when you "install" an app from a DMG? I ask because that is likely just the default sound the Mac makes when a copy/move operation is completed.

The "installation" you are doing to place a downloaded app in your Applications folder is really just copying the app from the mounted DMG file (on your SSD) to the /Applications folder which is *also* on your SSD. So that process is very fast, it can be on the order of a few seconds. So that give you little time to see and/or recognize the file copy progress dialog which will be the only feedback you get from this type of "installation."

While the Mac does use actual installers for some applications. That would be up to whoever wrote that application and what its requirements are. MS Word, Adobe Photoshop are examples of apps that use an actual installer. But you will find that most software downloaded off the internet is just installed by copying the file from the DMG (or zip) file to the /Applications folder.

Don't Expect an installer for every app like on Windows, many apps are self contained and require only copying to a location on your SSD that it can run from. Many expect that to be /Applications but you can often just drag it to the desktop and run it from there if you like.

Comment: That's the issue, the OP don't understand the simplicity of the mac software install process - this write up explains whats going on rather than 'It's being copied'.

Comment: Doesn't macOS have strict REQUIREMENTS for installers, e.g., an obligatory success confirmation after successful installation? The lack of such requirements isn't a sign of quality.

Comment: @user1580348 - No. Installation is often simply a file copy, nothing more, nothing less. There *is no installer*. If it takes more than a few seconds you will see a copy progress dialog, otherwise you'll just hear the 'operation finished' sound. *If* there is a true installer, for more complex installs requiring access to system areas, then it will conform to your expectation, a bit more like a windows installer.

Comment: @Tetsujin You didn't answer my question: "Doesn't macOS have strict REQUIREMENTS for installers, e.g., an obligatory success confirmation after successful installation?"

Comment: ***It's not an install, it's a file copy.*** The confirmation is the 'ding'. You seem to be expecting that 20 minutes of interminable 'thermometer' that windows insists on to do what really should be a 5 second job. It's not Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Apps on the Mac usually don't require "installation" like Windows apps do. You just need to get the app copied onto your hard drive. And that's exactly what you're doing when you drag it from a mounted disk image (.dmg) to the alias of your hard drive's Applications folder.

Macs and their Flash/SSD drives are so fast now that copying a whole app happens so quickly there's no time to even draw a copy-progress window, so you just hear the "copy done" sound!

Your app is fully "installed" (copied) when you hear that sound, and as proof, go see that it's inside your Applications folder, and double-click on it there and see that it successfully launches.

"There's no step three."
—Jeff Goldblum

Comment: Define "installation".